# Displacement from list of values

Tags: mesh

I have a mesh and a list of displacemnt values for each of the coordinates of a second mesh. The two meshes represent the same surface but the location of the vertices is different.
Would it be possible to apply such a displacement to the underformed original mesh?

To summarize:
Mesh 1 --> undeformed;
Mesh 2 --> deformed, different vertex locations, I have the list of displacement for each vertex

I want to apply the deformation I have for Mesh 2 to Mesh 1

Thanks

Comment: Could you submit some screenshots? It's not very clear, what exactly the issue is.

Comment: Sounds like how shapekeys work.  Have a basis mesh and a shapekey is just the new location for each vert. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15593/how-to-change-shapekey-vertex-position-through-python/15610#15610  Would be a simple script to add a shape key using your list of displacement vectors

Comment: Don't have a screenshot... I can ty and explain better.

Someone bent my original mesh (imagine is as a beam). To do so, this user had to transform the mesh so that the vertices of the new mesh are not at the same position as the vertex of my original mesh. This someone provided me with the displacement undergone by each vertex (as a list of values), the unbent version of his mesh and the bent version of his mesh. What I'm missing here is the bent version of MY original mesh. Do you think there's a way to bent my mesh the same way as he did by using the displacement list?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you should ask another question: about how apply coordinates to multiple vertexes. The existing question is so unclear that I dont' believe you will get any valuable help...

Comment: Would know how to apply coordinates to multiple vertices?